# Combinatorics - Choosing sticks

Tags: combinatorics

Seven sticks with lengths 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 and 17 inches are placed in a box. Three of the sticks are randomly selected. What is the probability that a triangle can be formed by joining the endpoints of the sticks? Express your answer as a common fraction.

**My work:** Using the triangle inequality, I counted $9$ ways to choose sticks: $(3,5,7) ; (3, 11, 13) ; (5,7,11) ; (5,11,13); (5,13,17); (7,11,13); (7,11,17); (7,13,17) ;(11,13,17) $.

**My Question:** I'm not sure how to count the total number of ways to choose sticks. Is choosing $(3,5,7)$ the same as choosing $(5,3,7)$, for example, or do those count as distinct ways to draw?

Comment: That is up to you and you will wind up with the same probability regardless.  It is probably easier for arithmetic if you treat them as the same.

Comment: Possible hint: What you're looking for is known as a binomial coefficient.

Comment: You mean 7 choose 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first stick, you have $7$ options. For the second and third, you have $6$ and $5$ options respectively. This means you can pick $3$ sticks from the $7$ in $7*6*5=210$ ways. Only $9*(3*2*1)=54$ of these lead to the desired outcome, so the probability would be $\frac{54}{210}=0.257...$

As others have pointed out, you can take order into account or not, as long as you do it consequently in your calculations. If you see different orders of sets of the same stick as equivalent, the number of ways to pick $3$ sticks from $7$ is indeed $\binom{7}{3}=35$ or $7$ choose $3$. Then, $\frac{9}{35}=\frac{54}{210}=0.257...$